# How to delete an entry from object in django

Tags: django

I am learning Django and I have some problem in query:
I have this code

```
class Publication(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
  headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.headline
```

In this code, with a Article objects I can add many Publication entry. How can I use query to delete an entry from Article object ?

Comment: Did you try the [RelatedManager.remove](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) method?

Answer (score 0):

Given `a` is you `Article`, and `p` is your `Publication` you want to remove, you can use the [**`.remove(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) function:

```
a.publications.remove(p)  # remove p from the publications of a
```

If `p` is not a publication related to `a`, then this call is basically a "no op": it will not change anything, nor will it raise an exception.

Note that here we do *not* remove the `Publiction` object itself, it is possible that other `Article`s still refer to `p`.

This is a "variadic" method, so if you for example want to remove `p1`, `p4` and `p5` from the `publications` of `a`, you can write:

```
a.publications.remove(p1, p4, p5)  # remove three publications from a
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use the `remove()` to delete it [demo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove).

If you want to delete all entries associated with it then use `clear()` as shown in [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear).

For more information about many_to_many please check this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Thanks